# Using the seriessum function

Tags: excel, sum

I'm having some trouble calculating the following expression's result in Excel

SUM(n=1 to 4) of 180/(1+0.05)^n

I read about the `seriessum` function, but I think this function is not able to apply the required step to the denominator. Could someone please suggest another solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need an extra layer of processing, either an *array formula* or *array processing* with a [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) wrapper.

The standard formula model is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(180/(1+0.05)^ROW(1:4))
```

The *array* formula model is:

```
=SUM(180/(1+0.05)^ROW(1:4))
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. If entered correctly, your results should be similar to the following.

[image: SUMSERIES formula]

Answer (score 1):

In **A1** enter:

=180/(1.05)^ROW()

and copy down to **A4**

then in **B1** enter:

=SUM(A:A)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That works but I wanted a solution where I wouldn't need to introduce one result at a time and them sum everything. Is it possible to do everything in one cell, with some kind of function I don't know about?

Comment: @JoãoLima  ..................Perhaps......your formula looks like one of the *Financial* functions.........like *NPV()* .............we should investigate them.

Comment: €Gary's Student I think the NPV() function is close to what I was looking for.

Comment: @JoãoLima  I would use **Jeeped**'s solution